# Unknown error when executing shell script

Tags: shell, ubuntu-9.10

I have the following shell script (bash script) at cron.sh file

```
#!/bin/bash

WORKON_HOME="/home/django/domains/example.com"
PROJECT_ROOT="/home/django/domains/example.com/django-project/"

. $WORKON_HOME/bin/activate

cd $PROJECT_ROOT
python manage.py cron
```

But when i run:

```
$ sh cron.sh
```

I got the following error

```
: not found
: not found
/bin/activatepen /home/django/domains/example.com
```

Server info

```
cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=9.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=karmic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 9.10"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your script has the wrong line endings. Pass it through `dos2unix`.

Comment: I'll be grateful forever Ignacio
I was using eclipse at windows for edit remote files, and forget to set the delimiter line to unix.
in two days is my birthday and I'll put a candle ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you didn't show us everything in the code that you're trying to run.  So I'll answer generically instead:

Run the script using `sh -x cron.sh` which will give you very verbose output of what it's doing up until the `python` invocation.  If the errors are before that point, you know it's in the `sh` half and what caused them.  If after that, you'll have to debug the `python` script.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
bash -x cron.sh
```

or

```
./cron.sh
```

make sure to make it executable.